# Two Laravel Sub Query (One Model two relationships)

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to ask if there is a way to get two subqueries for one model using with().

Model Computer:

```
class Computer extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');
    }
}
```

Model User:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function department() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Department');
    }
    public function roles() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Role');
    }
}
```

Query:

```
Computer::where("pc_no" $request->pc_no)->with(["user.[department, roles]"]);
```

Output needs to be:

```
{
 computer: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "PC1"
    department: {
     id: 1,
     name: "Encoding"
    },
    roles: [
     {
      id: 1,
      name: "Typist"
     },
     {
      id: 2,
      name: "Filer"
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Computer::where("pc_no", $request->pc_no)
->with(["user.department", "user.roles"])
->get();
```

This will net you something like

```
{
    computer: 
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "PC1"
            user: 
            {
                department: 
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Encoding"
                },
                roles: 
                [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "Typist"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Filer"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

If you don't want the user part, you probably need to use an Eloquent Resource. You can create one from the console with the command

```
php artisan make:resource Computer
```

Then, make the ToArray method as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Computer extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'department' => $this->user->department,
            'roles' => $this->user->roles,
            // Any other param you want in your json/array should be set here explicitly
        ];
    }
}
```

And finally, call that use that resource in your controller.

```php
use App\Http\Resources\Computer as ComputerResource;
...
$computer = Computer::where("pc_no", $request->pc_no)
->with(["user.department", "user.roles"])
->get();
$computer_resource = new ComputerResource($computer);
```

`$computer_resource->toArray()` should give you the format you want.

Comment: this is not what he wants.

Comment: Doesn't he want to load both of user's relationships?

Comment: he doesn't want the users part.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this [Laravel union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#unions)

or

try to do something like this with the `with()`.

```
Your Model::where(function($query){
    $query->where('author_id', Auth::user()->id);
  })->with(function($query){
    $query->where('your condition');
    $query->where('your condition');
  })->get()
```